# how to skip lines starting with # in two files

Tags: python, python-3.x

My input files (`1.txt` and `2.txt`) include the comment lines with a hash `#`. I want to ignore those lines while reading the input files but my codes ignores those lines only in `1.txt`. How can I ignore those comment lines in both/multiple input files `1.txt` and `2.txt`?

**1.txt:**

```
#data 1 3 4 2
#normal data
2.5 1.2
5.5 6.5
3.2 6.3
```

**2.txt:**

```
#saved 0.2 11
#data
#from x data
50.20   13.7
165.55  21.0
128.64  23.0
```

Here is my code:

```
with open("1.txt") as f1, open("2.txt") as f2, open("output.txt", mode="w") as out:


    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):

        first_data, second_data = line1.split(), line2.split()
        if not line1.startswith('#') or line2.startswith('#'):
```

Comment: if not line1.startswith('#') and not line2.startswith('#'):

Comment: Could you add a sample of 1.txt and 2.txt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter lines before applying `zip(f1, f2)`.

Example :

```
with open("1.txt") as f1, open("2.txt") as f2, open("output.txt", mode="w") as out:

    lines1 = [l for l in f1.readlines() if not l.startswith('#')]
    lines2 = [l for l in f2.readlines() if not l.startswith('#')]

    for line1, line2 in zip(lines1, lines2):

         first_data, second_data = line1.split(), line2.split()
         print(first_data, second_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if not line1.startswith('#') or not line2.startswith('#'):
```

To ignore any line in either file that starts with `'#'`

Answer (score 1):

Fun with regex:

```
import re

# [.....] 

x = re.match("^[^ #].*$", line_from_file1) # this expression takes the lines not beginning with # from file1
if x:
    ## line from file 1 does not start with #
    pass

y = re.match("^[^ #].*$", line_from_file2)
if y:
    ## line from file2 does not start with #
    pass

if x and y:
    #neither line from file1 nor line from file2 start with #
    pass
```